# Way stroke outline number using swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

is there anyway to draw or stroke a number using swift for iOS? The number has to be in the outline style. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an  NSAttributedString. UITextField can display attributed strings using the attributedText property.

```
let number = 5 // Whatever number you are looking to output
let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12.0)
let attribs = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
    NSStrokeColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName: font,
    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: 1.0
]

let outlinedNumber = NSAttributedString(string: "\(number)", attributes: attribs)
```

Play with the various attributes to get the effect you want.

Comment: tried this but it's just adding the text nothing else. what I want to achieve is something like this one http://www.wpclipart.com/signs_symbol/alphabets_numbers/outlined_numbers/outline/number_2_outline.png

Comment: I've to display it on a label